# Подсчитать сколько выведенных пар?

Tags: c#

подскажите пожалуйста как вывести в консоль количество пар, а не их имя?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BINANCE_0._1._1

{
    public class RateLimit
    {
        public string rateLimitType { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        public string filterType { get; set; }
        public string minPrice { get; set; }
        public string maxPrice { get; set; }
        public string tickSize { get; set; }
        public string minQty { get; set; }
        public string maxQty { get; set; }
        public string stepSize { get; set; }
        public string minNotional { get; set; }
        public int? limit { get; set; }
        public int? maxNumAlgoOrders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Symbol
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string baseAsset { get; set; }
        public int baseAssetPrecision { get; set; }
        public string quoteAsset { get; set; }
        public int quotePrecision { get; set; }
        public List<string> orderTypes { get; set; }
        public bool icebergAllowed { get; set; }
        public List<Filter> filters { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string timezone { get; set; }
        public long serverTime { get; set; }
        public List<RateLimit> rateLimits { get; set; }
        public List<object> exchangeFilters { get; set; }
        public List<Symbol> symbols { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //заходим на биржу
            String url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo";
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Подключение к бирже Бинанс " + (((HttpWebResponse)httpWebResponse).StatusDescription));

            string response;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //Json десериализация
            var Dynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

            foreach (var item in Dynamic.symbols)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + item.symbol);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Скрин того, что выводит. Пары это  BNBBTC, ETHBTC и т.д.
[image]

Если написать строку так

```
Console.WriteLine(Dynamic.symbols.Select(x => x.symbol).Distinct().Count());
```

то выводит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пар чего? Поясните что вы хотите видеть?

Comment: Зачем нужны подробности про http web request? Их можно вырезать без ущерба для понимания вопроса. Сделайте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! У вас есть List<Symbol> вы из него что хотите посчитать/вывести?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Dynamic.symbols.Count)`

Answer (score 1):

Количество уникальных пар:

```
Console.WriteLine(Dynamic.symbols.Select(x => x.symbol).Distinct().Count());
```

Общее количество пар:
    Console.WriteLine(Dynamic.symbols.Select(x => x.symbol).Count());

Например, для:

```
var Dynamic = new RootObject { symbols = new List<Symbol> { new Symbol { symbol = "ETHBTC" }, new Symbol {symbol = "ETHBTC"}, new Symbol {symbol = "LTCBTC"} } };
```

Получим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, кстати, что ранее порекомендовали `LINQPad`) Такая красота)